# SQL Server Storage sql_variant

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-internals

```
USE tempdb ;
GO

DROP TABLE tbl ;
GO

CREATE TABLE tbl
(
    i SQL_VARIANT NOT NULL
) ;
GO

INSERT INTO tbl (i)
    VALUES (1) ;
GO

SELECT i FROM tbl ; 
GO

DBCC IND ('tempdb','tbl',-1) ;
GO

DBCC TRACEON (3604) ; -- Page dump will go the console
GO

DBCC PAGE ('tempdb',1,157,3) ;
GO
```

- Record Size = 17B
- 30000400 01000001 00110038 01010000 00
- TagA = 0x30       = 1B
- TagB = 0x00       = 1B
- Null Bitmap Offset    = 0x0004    = 2B
- Column Count      = 0x0001    = 2B
- Null Bitmap       = 0x00      = 1B
- Variable-Length Columns Count = 0x0001    = 2B
- Variable-Length Column Offset Array  = 0x0011     = 2B
- This is the sql_variant encoding for integers...***I guess*** = 0x0138 = 2B
- Our integer column    = 0x00000001 = 4B

```
    SELECT
      SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(i , 'BaseType') AS BaseType      -- SYSNAME NVARCHAR(128)
    , SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(i , 'Precision') AS [Precision]  -- INT
    , SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(i , 'Scale') AS Scale            -- INT
    , SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(i , 'TotalBytes') AS TotalBytes  -- INT
    , SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(i , 'Collation') AS [Collation]  -- SYSNAME NVARCHAR(128)
    , SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(i , 'MaxLength') AS MaxLength    -- INT
FROM
      tbl ;
GO
```

My questions:

1. 0x3801...what is that
2. i = 328792402 Huh?  Where did this come from?
3. SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY() says I have an integer. Why does it not choose tinyint?
4. Does anyone know where SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY() can be found. Must I use the DAC to get at it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first 2 answers are from the SQL Server Internals Book p.278

1. `0x38` is 56 in decimal. This indicates `int` in `sys.types` (`system_type_id` column)
2. `0x01` is the version number of the `sql_variant` format (always 1 in SQL Server 2008)
3. This is the way the literal `1` is always interpreted in SQL Server. e.g. `SELECT 1 AS foo INTO NewTable` will create a new column of integer datatype. Use an explicit cast if you want it to be treated as a different datatype.
4. This is part of the product source code. You cannot view the definition.

BTW: If you are looking at other datatypes as well you may encounter some additional bytes between the version number and the column value as follows.

1. `numeric`/`decimal` have 1 byte each for precision and scale.
2. `[n][var]char` have 2 bytes for max length and 4 bytes for collation id.
3. `[var]binary` have 2 bytes for max length.